# No way to start app from Play-Store, but apk runs fine

Tags: android

My Android app runs fine in the emulator and on my device using android studio. I managed to sign the app and upload it to the play store without errors. But, when I install it from the play store, it won't show up with the other apps and inside the play store the button to start the app is missing.

In my `AndroidManifest.xml` there is exactly one activity with:

```
    <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
```

According to the official [doku](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html), `android:enabled` defaults to true, so I left it out.

It seems like I am missing some other option to activate the app. Is there anything else I can check/set/activate?

Comment: Post your whole manifest.

Comment: i posted it to: http://pastebin.com/t68vsN04

Comment: Well I don't see anything wrong in the manifest... have you tried using the fully qualified name of your StartActivity? Also, possibly make sure that all your packages are setup correctly.

Comment: I'm now using only fully qualified names in the manifest. Upload to play store worked without problems, but right now I am only seeing an older version there. I'll check back in a few hours. Thx for your advice.

Comment: npace : thx your advice helped. Now I can start the app after installing from play store. Thank you very much. Unfortunately I can't mark your answer as accepted, so i only "+"ed it.

Answer (score 0):

try uninstalling the unsigned app from the device and re-install your app from the playstore

Comment: Sorry for not mentioning this, but I already tried it and it didn't work. Thanks anyway.